# The Legend of Zelda (Original) Virtual Console can't select item to use on b!

Tags: nintendo-wii, virtual-console, the-legend-of-zelda

I bought *The Legend of Zelda* for Virtual Console and my problem is, that I can't select any item on the <kbd>B</kbd> button in the subscreen.

Of course I read the discription that says I should use the d-pad (I use the Wiimote) but it doesn't work.

I also tried a GameCube controller and it's the same effect. All other things works fine, but this doesn't work either.

Can anyone tell me how to select different items on <kbd>B</kbd>, please?

Comment: To clarify, you've actually gotten an item you can use with <kbd>B</kbd>? A boomerang, a candle, a bomb or some such?

Comment: Yes I got the bow, but I couldn't select it :/
And I really don't know why, that's my problem.

Comment: So if you use the Wii remote, and use the "1" and "2" buttons for A and B, they do not work? CyberSkull already asked what my initial question was about to be.

Comment: No they work, all in the game work fine, except for the select to use a different item on b (the 1 Button on the Wiimote) in the subscreen. I tried it, but I can't select it (with the d-pad, how the discription tell me), I can save the game, but I can't select an item

Comment: Haha, okay I'm just stupid. Don't know that I only can use the Bow, when I have arrows... It works now. *headdesk*
But thanks, for trying to help me :3

Comment: Post that as the answer. ;)

Answer (score 9):

As you're referring to your bow, you've probably just left the first dungeon, meaning you don't have any arrows. Without arrows, the bow is unequippable. Buy \ Find some arrows and you should be able to equip the bow to your B menu, alternatively, find another item you can equip (bombs, boomerang, etc).